# set_codes in multiIndexed pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, indexing, multi-index

I want to multiIndex an array of data.
Initially, I was indexing my data with datetime, but for some later applications, I had to add another numeric index (that goes from 0 the len(array)-1).

I have written those little lines:

```py
O = [0.701733664614, 0.699495411782, 0.572129320819, 0.613315597684, 0.58079660603, 0.596638918579, 0.48453382119]
Ab = [datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 11, 14, 0), datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 21, 10, 0), datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 21, 14, 0), datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 1, 10, 0), datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 1, 14, 0), datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 11, 10, 0), datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 11, 14, 0)]
tst = pd.Series(O,index=Ab)
ld = len(tst)
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([(x for x in range(0,ld)),Ab], names=['id','dtime'])
print (index)
data = pd.Series(O,index=index)
```

But when printting *index*, I get some bizzare ''codes'': 
The levels & names are perfect, but the codes go from 0 to 763...764 times (instead of one)!

I tried to add the *set_codes* command:

```py
index.set_codes([x for x in range(0,ld)], level=0)
print (index)
```

I vain, I have the following error :

> > ValueError: Unequal code lengths: [764, 583696]

**the initial pandas series:**

print (tst)

2005-01-01 14:00:00    0.544177

2005-01-01 14:00:00    0.544177

2005-01-21 14:00:00    0.602239

...

2019-05-21 10:00:00    0.446813

2019-05-21 14:00:00    0.466573

Length: 764, dtype: float64

**the new expected one**

id    dtime

0     2005-01-01 14:00:00    0.544177

1     2005-01-01 14:00:00    0.544177

2     2005-01-21 14:00:00    0.602239

...

762   2019-05-21 10:00:00    0.446813

763   2019-05-21 14:00:00    0.466573

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create new index by [`MultiIndex.from_arrays`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_arrays.html) and reassign to `Series`:

```
s.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([np.arange(len(s)), s.index], names=['id','dtime'])
```

Comment: just another little question, what have I to do if I want to acess a specific date?
I just can acess the last value doing, as an example, this: ```s[0][0]```

Comment: @Nour - use [`Series.xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.xs.html) - e.g. `s.xs('2005-01-01', level=1)`

Comment: I've got this: _id
759    0.570497_ 
I mean,how can I input some id and return a specific date.
Sorry, I misspoke ^^'

Comment: then use `print (s.loc[5].index[0])`

Comment: what is "s" in s.index? where did that come from?

Comment: @Boris - it is series, here `tst`